# iOS - Push Notifications not responding as expected

Tags: ios, swift3, push-notification, cloudkit

I have created a CloudKit subscription to a specific class that fires a push notification on the object creation or update.

That code goes as following:

```
    // Create the predicate
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordId = %@", RECORD_ID)

// Create a subscription specifying the record type, predicate and notification options
let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Notes", predicate: predicate, options: [.firesOnRecordUpdate, .firesOnRecordCreation])

// Create a CloudKit notification object
let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
notificationInfo.shouldBadge = true

// Set the subscriptor's notification object to the new CloudKit notification object
subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

// Save the subscription to the database
let publicDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
publicDatabase.save(subscription) { (subs, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Failed to save subscription:", err)
        return
    }
}
```

The subscription gets saved successfully in the server.

I wanted to create a silent notification, and I'm handling the notification (when received) as following:

```
    import UserNotifications

// Register for push notifications
let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (success, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Failed to request oauth for notifications:", err)
    }
}
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:", deviceToken)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to register notifications_ error:", error)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("------------------------")
    print("Receiving updates from the server") 

    // Convert the userInfo parameter to a CKNotification object
    let cloudKitNotification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo)

    // Get the body of the notification
    let alertBody = cloudKitNotification.alertBody
    print("alertBody:", alertBody ?? "")

    // Get the new or modified record form the CKQueryNotification object
    if cloudKitNotification.notificationType == CKNotificationType.query {
        guard let queryNotification = cloudKitNotification as? CKQueryNotification else {
            print("could not cast the query notification")
            return
        }
        let recordId = queryNotification.recordID
        print("recordId:", recordId ?? "")
    }
}
```

Here's where the problem happens.

If I'm using the app and an update was sent to the server, my `didReceiveRemoteNotification` fires and everything works properly, however if my app is in the background, my app_notification badge changes (increases by 1) when a push notification is received but the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` doesn't fire.

My question is, how can I handle the push notification entry when it arrives?

I have set the `Required background modes` in the `Info.plis` file with `App downloads content from the network` and `App downloads content in response to push notifications`

One more thing I noticed, If I set my `notificationInfo.shouldBadge` to false I receive no push notifications.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Any hint on how to bypass this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notifications are not guaranteed to arrive, especially if the user goes into airplane mode, loses connection, etc. And, even if you do receive the notice, when your app is running, you can't execute any processing. This means you must assume every time you start the app that there are notifications still waiting for processing (those that you received while you weren't in the app as well as those that you never received any push notice for, for whatever reason).

So, When you start the app, you need to issue a `CKFetchNotificationsChangesOperation` and look for new notifications that you haven't processed yet.

You create the `CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation` operation, and set the `notificationChangedBlock`. That block will be called once for each notification pulled from the server. You can evaluate if it's already marked as "read" yet. If not, then handle it however you normally do in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

Optionally, you can also set code in the `fetchNotificationChangesCompletionBlock` that will fire once, at the very end of the operation, after all notifications have been fetched from the server.

Comment: So lets say. I had 3 push notifications pending for a user profile data update. When I enter the app in another device and check for pending OP it will 'say' that I've 3 pending OP. I can check lets say by its subscriptionID and if they're all the same I can only fetch the latest one right? Do you think in this case that I should use the `fetchNotificationChangesCompletionBlock` instead to fetch the latest one? There are particular cases that a subscription is only for a specific type so I don't have to iterate through all of them.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I believe you will still have to iterate through the notificationCangedBlock because, looking at those completion blocks, that's the only one that actually receives the notif. The notifs are not passed into the final completion block, so you have to collect them yourself. Two thing that will help: the notifs you receive in the first block will be marked read/unread (assuming you update the status when processing them), so you can continue past ones you've seen. Second, that

Comment: ...operation can be initiated with a change token, which is basically the "read pointer" indicating how far you've read before. So if you save the change token each time and start subsequent calls with the latest token you've received, you should narrow down the number of notifs you have to wade through. But I don't know any way to simply grab only the absolute last one.

Comment: I've read as well that the best way is to cache the latest token then in the application load fetch the notifications starting in that token point then cache the last one as well. That's the approach I'll take. I'm in doubt that if I mark the read notifs as Read, will the other devices that haven't read them be able to read them or will the read mark be per-device? Thanks for helping

Comment: If you mark the notif as read on one device, that same user on all other devices will still see them in the query, but with the status marked read. The apple docs on this matter are wrong... they say the query only returns unread notifications. However the query clearly returns both read and unread notifications (since the change token) and one of the wwdc videos explains that's on purpose and describes a scenario where an app needs to see all notifs, read and unread, on all devices.

Comment: I will take the 'token' approach; caching it in user defaults then fetching from the previous point and I'll do it on every device. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck!